# How could I write this more succinctly?

Tags: css, css-selectors, text-align

How could I re-write this to where I'm not repeating `text-align: center;` several times?

```
section.info h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

section.info h5 {
    text-align: center;
}

section.info p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, since text-align is an [inherited property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align), you can affect the section as a whole by applying the style to the parent element:

```
section.info { text-align: center; }
```

Comment: He may have other elements under that parent which he doesn't want center aligned.

Comment: @AniMenon Then selectively override descendants as necessary, that's a fundamental CSS pattern.

Comment: @torazaburo that would be a pain if you have too many elements which don't need the style.

Comment: @AniMenon The OP indicated two headers and a paragraph as having the same style; I think that's enough to indicate the style of the section as a whole. Then again, we'll never know unless he says so himself

Comment: @AniMenon Right. So the question for the OP is, is `section.info` **basically** centered with some exceptions, or are the centered sub-elements the exceptions?

Answer (score 2):

this code will help you

```
section.info h2, section.info h5, section.info p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although not all browsers support it:

```
section.info :-webkit-any(h2, h5, p) { }
```

Other browsers support this under other prefixes, eg `-moz-any`. This feature is likely to become standardized under the name `:matches`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use

```
section.info {
    text-align: center;
}
```

and it will affect all of the child elements automatically. If for some reason you need to be specific you can do this:

```
section.info h2, section.info h5, section.info p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Your second example won't work like your'e hoping it will. Introducing the > also changes the meaning.

Comment: It means that the h2, the h5, and the p that are directed children of section.info will have text-align: center; applied to them. Which may be worth knowing if the OP needs to overwrite existing styles.

Comment: No, that's not what it means. It means `h2` which is a direct child of `section.info`, and **any** `h5` or `p`.

Comment: @torazaburo Ah! right you are. I stand corrected and have updated the above.

Answer (score 1):

Put all of then in a class & write the css property as `.class_name{ /* css_property */ }` instead of specifying the property for each tag separately. In your case you may use `section.info` in place of `class_name`.

For example:

```css
.center-text {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-text">Data</div>
<p class="center-text">Data</p>
<h1 class="center-text">Data</h1>
```

Comment: If you're going to define such a class, why not give it a better name, like `center-text`?

Comment: @torazaburo meaningful class name yes :).

Comment: Because this is the same that would have been written as `<div align="center">`, `<p align="center">`, `<h1 align="center">` (or similarily) in earlier times . It just defeats the seperation of markup and styling and adds a whole lot of unmaintainability. Same as using Bootstrap classes (`xs-column-4` etc.).

Comment: @Jost Firstly, [`<div> align` is deprecated](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_div_align.asp). Secondly, there is no "unmaintainability" here.

Comment: @AniMenon Ok, then take a page with 1k centered `h1`s, and change them to left-aligned. This is equivalent to using align directly, and the reason this is wrong is  the same reason `align` was deprecated.

Comment: @Jost just change the [`text-align` to `left` for `h1` tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#adef-align). Whats your point?

Comment: @AniMenon So then you have a CSS-rule `h1.center-text {text-align: left;}`? That would be quite unintuitive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113277/discussion-between-ani-menon-and-jost).

Comment: @Jost on the contrary, this is a well-established pattern sometimes called "micro-classes". Some people don't like microclasses; others do. However, being a matter of personal preference, a downvote is hardly justified.